# UseEffect hook not updating prop correctly

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

So I am a novice to React and JS in general and am currently working on a little project where I am trying to fetch an image through a URL which then allows me to crop it with a cropper overlay. To set the image property, I use setImage which gets called on in the onClick function onURLImage. Right now, my problem is that the image is fetched and presented on the page, however, the cropper isn't created. I tried checking the console with logs to see if the hook gets called upon, and it does, but for some reason the cropper isn't created. I am unsure as to what I am doing wrong. I tried using componentDidUpdate, however I don't really understand how it works in my scenario. I would appreciate any form of help!

```
const App = () => {
    const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState('');
    const [image, setImage] = useState(null);
    const [cropper, setCropper] = useState();

    const [left, setLeft] = useState(0);
    const [top, setTop] = useState(0);
    const [right, setRight] = useState(0);
    const [bottom, setBottom] = useState(0);

    const containerRef = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("render");
        // If image exist
        if (image) {
            const img = document.getElementById('image');

            // If the cropper exists already, just replace it
            if (cropper) {
                cropper && cropper.replace(image);

            // Otherwise, create the cropper
            } else {
                setCropper(new Cropper(img, {
                    viewMode: 2,
                    zoomable:true,
                    crop(event) {
                        setLeft(getLeftPctg(event.detail.x, event.target.naturalWidth));
                        setTop(getTopPctg(event.detail.y, event.target.naturalHeight));
                        setRight(getRightPctg(event.detail.x, event.detail.width, event.target.naturalWidth));
                        setBottom(getBottomPctg(event.detail.y, event.detail.height, event.target.naturalHeight));
                    },
                }));
            }
        } else {
            if (cropper) {
                cropper.destroy();
                setCropper('');
            }
        }
    }, [image]);
```

```
 /**
     * Arrow Function onURLImage(): Event Handler
     * Insert Image from a URL
     */
    const onURLImage = () => {
        const url:String = document.getElementById("url-input").value;
        let pos:Number = url.indexOf("?");

        if (pos !== -1){
            let draft = url.slice(0, pos) + ".png" + url.slice(pos);
            let src = draft.replace("/#/site/", "/t/");
            setImage(src);
            //handleImage(src);
            document.getElementById("url-input").value = "";
        } else {
            //TODO: Error Handling
            window.alert("Please use one of the provided URLs!");
            document.getElementById("url-input").value = "";
        }
    }
```

I also tried updating the image through a handler however that did not create the cropper either.

```
const handleImage = (url) => {
        setImage(url);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the DOM in a useEffect because you haven't been mounted in the dom yet. You'll either need to useLayoutEffect, or you'll want to useRef and pass the ref down to the dom component.

See also: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#uselayouteffect

Comment: I am a bit confused, since I see the useEffect Hook being called on in the console, so shouldn't it then also create the cropper? So it shows me:  image is being fetched per url ->handleImage gets activated and sets the Image -> useEfect is called on and the page is rendered.

Answer (score 0):

Do this if image is in `containerRef`.

```
containerRef.current.getElementById('image')
```